# How can I use child selector > (or + etc.) with by.css on an element?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

Given:

```
var someDivElement = element(by.css('div.main'));
```

Now, I would like to select further child elements on `someDivElement`, but with child selector. Unfortunately, the child selector won't work that way:

```
var childElement = someDivElement.element(by.css('> section > span'));
```

This will result in an **invalid css path error**. **Is there a workaround?**
What I dont wan't to do is following:

```
var childElement = element(by.css(someDivElement.locator().value + '> section > span'));
```

UPDATE:
Html-Code looks something like this:

```
<div class="main">
    <section>
        <span></span> <!-- I want ONLY this span -->
        <div class="main">
             <section>
                 <span></span> <!-- this span i don't want -->
             </section>
         </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

If I do as suggested:

```
var childElement = someDivElement.element(by.css('div.main > section > span'));
```

I still end up with a warning `more than one element found for locator By.cssSelector`

Comment: It seems you are trying to get the child elements of the `someDivElement`, using `by.css()` method only, right?

Comment: `var childElement = someDivElement.element(by.css('div.main > section'))` should work right? If I am not mistaken, it is illegal to start with operator `>` or `+`, etc without having element beforehand. It is a bit redundant I think

Comment: If you do as suggested, you get more than one element found warning because the sequence `div.main > section > span` matches 2 elements. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. One way of doing this is to get all the child elements under parent element using chaining technique and then use [`get()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get) or [`first()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first) methods to get the element *(You can even use `filter()` or `map()` function to get the precise element too)*. Here's how -

   ```
   var someDivElement = element.all(by.css('div.main')).first();
   var childElement = someDivElement.$$(by.css('section > span')).first();
   //OR
   var someDivElement = $$('div.main').first();
   var childElement = someDivElement.$$(by.css('section > span')).get(0);
   ```
2. If you are looking for css selectors that can do this work, then you can do it this way -

   ```
   var childElement = $('div.main:nth-of-type(even) > section >span');
   ```

[`nth-of-type(even)`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) function will return the first div. If you want to get the second div then use odd instead of even. You can also provide numbers to the function.

3. Other way is to get the locator value of the parent element which is an [`ElementFinder`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder) and then use it. Here's how -

   ```
   var childElement = element.all(by.css(someDivElement.elementArrayFinder_.locator_.value + '> section > span')).first();
   ```
4. You can even use the `locator()` function that you have mentioned in your question using `first()` or `get()` function.

---

**EDIT:**
To avoid `IndexOutOfBound Exception` in the case of `first()` and `get()` functions, you can write a custom `wait()` function to see if the element count is greater than 0 and then proceed with operations. Here's how -

```
var someDivElement = element.all(by.css('div.main'));
var childElement;
browser.wait(function(){
    return someDivElement.count().then(function(count){
        return count > 0;
    });
}, 10000); //Wait for 10 seconds before timing out
childElement = someDivElement.$$(by.css('section > span')).first();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I don't want index out of bound exceptions in case if there is no element in the DOM, so first() or get(0) is not an option. My final thought was the css-way (:nth-of-type), too...

Comment: @sl3dg3 you can check if element is present before performing operation on it. Or write a custom `wait()` function to avoid it. Updated answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: This wait-method is interesting, gotta try that soon... I wonder if it is possible to wrap that in a function, which would return me in any case an `ElementFinder`, e.g. in a page object?

Comment: @sl3dg3, `wait()` function can only be used to wait for an event. In this wait until the count of elements becomes greater than 0. But you can use it as a gate to return the ElementFinder(for ex, return element in `.then()` function chained to `wait()`). Thanks

Comment: The thing is: How do I get an 'empty' childElement if there is none? As far as I understand, the `.then()` function is only called if there is at least one element, resolved by the `wait()` - function. If there is no element, I wouldn't be able to return anything, would I?

Comment: true @sl3dg3. `wait()` function times out with a predefined time. If you want you can explicitly pass a timeout value to wait() function. If you want to get childElements that are empty, then write the statement outside without chaining. Protractor by default holds the execution until `wait()` function finishes executing. Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
var childElement = someDivElement.element(by.css('section'));
```

or in a page file this might look like:

```
someDivElement:{get: function(){ return element(by.css('div.main')); }}
childElement:  {get: function(){ return this.someDivElement.element(by.css('section')) }},
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to add a wrapper element where you will define your own selector (*For example, `this`*). Suppose, the selector `this` will point to the current element.

The custom selector function will be something like this:

```
function myCustomSelector(referenceElement, selector){
  //
  var targetElement = element(by.css(selector));
  // if selector has "this" reference
  if(/^this\s/.test(selector)){
    referenceElement.setAttribute('temporary-reference-attribute','1');
    selector = selector.replace(/^this/,'[temporary-reference-attribute]');
    targetElement = element(by.css(selector));
    referenceElement.removeAttribute('temporary-reference-attribute');
  }
  return targetElement;
}
```

And then call:

```
var childElement = myCustomSelector(someDivElement, 'this > section');
```

Comment: `setAttribute` seems to be an unknown method... same for `removeAttribute`